# O que faz o "group by 1" e porque gera erros no Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Queria saber o que o `group by 1` faz no `MySQL` ?

Estou curioso pois tenho uma query bem complexa em `MySQL` e funciona muito bem, só que estou tentando usar ela no `Laravel` e recebo um erro no retorno. Se eu rodar a mesma query em um editor `MySQL` não há erros.

**Segue a query:**

```
select posicao_id, distancia, max(created_at) created_at
from dispositivos
group by 1
```

**Segue o erro:**

```
"errorInfo": [
    "42000",
    1055,
    "'laravel.dispositivos.distancia' isn't in GROUP BY"
]
```

**Observações:** se eu desabilito a opção `strict => false` no arquivo `config/database.php` ele volta a funcionar mas qual as consequências disso ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### GROUP BY

A claúsula [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) aceita dois tipos de informação: *texto* e *inteiros*. Quando um valor inteiro é informado, você estará informando — implicitamente — a posição da coluna que será utilizada na cláusula supra.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `gender` FROM `users` GROUP BY 3
```

**Equivale ao código:**

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `gender` FROM `users` GROUP BY `gender`
```

---

### Erro no Laravel

Por padrão, toda informação passada nos métodos: `table`, `select`, `groupBy`, `orderBy` etc. São postas entre acentos graves. Isso irá garantir que, ao utilizar nomes de colunas como `date` e `order` (que são funções nativas do *SQL*), o código não falhe, pois os nomes entre acentos graves não serão interpretados pelo *MySQL*, por exemplo.

**Exemplo no Laravel:**

```
$test = \DB::table('users')->select('id')->groupBy('1');    
dd($test->toSQL());
```

> *"select `id` from `users` group by `1`"*

Observe que na saída acima, o método `groupBy` automaticamente coloca o valor numérico entre acentos graves. Fazendo que o *MySQL* interprete como uma coluna e não a posição dela.

Para corrigir esta falha, você pode usar o método `DB::raw`, por exemplo:

```
$test = \DB::table('users')->select('id')->groupBy(\DB::raw('1'));    
dd($test->toSQL());
```

> *"select `id` from `users` group by 1"*

Com o `DB::raw`, você irá informar ao Laravel que não é para alterar ou escapar aquele código.

---

### Strict Mode

De acordo com a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict), o *strict mode* controla como o MySQL manipula valores inválidos ou ausentes em instruções de mudança de dados.

Apesar de não gerar um erro, é gerado um aviso ao utilizar o `select` com o modo estrito setado como `false`.

Com o modo estrito ativo, o *MySQL* irá gerar erros ao tentar utilizar valores inválidos (como no exemplo do `group by`). Com o modo supra inativo, o *Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de dados (SGDB)* irá tentar ajustar o valor para que tais erros não sejam exibidos, porém o resultado da consulta pode ser afetado.

Comment: Sinceridade, isso não é um falha do `Eloquent` (`Laravel é o framework Web`) e `Eloquent` que é utilizado dentro do Laravel e também pode ser usado fora, ou seja, ele é independente do `Laravel` mesmo sendo feito pelo mesmo cara. Porque é assim? ***porque não são todos os bancos que trabalham da mesma forma e o padrão colocado por ele é utilizado em todos os bancos. Vale muito lembrar que existe em todos os seu métodos a forma de contornar `SQL Raw` e isso você explicou***. Não me leve a mau, mas, eu precisa contestar a sua resposta nesse tópico porque **Erro** é aquilo que não funciona.

Answer (score 3):

> Serve para agrupar pela primeira coluna, independentemente do que é
>   chamado. Você pode fazer o mesmo com ORDER BY.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT account_id, open_emp_id
          /\          /\
       coluna 1      coluna 2

FROM account
GROUP BY 1;
```

Na consulta acima, **GROUP BY 1** refere-se *ao first column in select statement* que é  account_id.

Resposta original do [Stack**overflow** inglês aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392730/what-does-sql-clause-group-by-1-mean).